# @mui/styles is not compatible with React.StrictMode or React 18

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a project with react v17 and `mui` v5, now I am upgrading the react version to v18. I am getting issues on the npm install after updating package.json to the latest react version.

The `mui` documentation says **@mui/styles is not compatible with React.StrictMode or React 18**
I have used `@mui/styles` in my project so many times. I have used `makeStyles` and `withStyles` from `@mui/styles` API, so how can I replace `makeStyles` and `withStyles`?

My code:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    color: (props) => props.color,
  },
});
```

### Another file

```
import { withStyles } from '@mui/styles';

const styles = {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
};

function MyComponent(props) {
  return <div className={props.classes.root} />;
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score -1):

From your `index.js` file, remove the strict mode and that should get rid of the error, material UI and react strict mode are not fully compatible but this is sure to be addressed in future versions.

for example, change

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

to

```
root.render(
    <App />
);
```

to render your app component.

Comment: removing strict mode is not a solution, makeStyles and withStyles are deprecated and we need to upgrade the MUI and use styled-components or sx props.